# Integer expression expected in if statement

Tags: bash, shell-script, osx

I have a small shutdown script, if the Mac runs over 24 hours it will shutdown. I'm not really experienced in bash scripts, but I did this:

```
!/bin/bash

#Maximum number of days to be up
max=1

#Get the uptime days and assign it to a variable
uptime_days=`uptime | cut -d " " -f 5`

if [ $uptime_days -ge $max ]
  then 
  shutdown -h now
fi

exit 0
```

now i get this error message:

```
./shutdown: line 9: (: days,: integer expression expected
```

Anybody can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for macOS. We get the boot timestamp, then the current timestamp in seconds then some math and voila.

```
#!/bin/bash
BOOT_TIME=$(sysctl -n kern.boottime | sed -e 's/.* sec = \([0-9]*\).*/\1/')
CURR_TIME=$(date +%s)
MAX_UPDAYS=1 #Days

DAYS_UP=$(( ( $CURR_TIME - $BOOT_TIME) / 86400 ))
if [ $DAYS_UP -ge ${MAX_UPDAYS} ];then
   shutdown -h now
fi
```

Comment: Can I enter a name of a specific Mac? for example I want to shutdown the mac121 instead of my mac where this script runs

Comment: @Gunter you mean another computer altogether? This gets the uptime for the current system. You would copy this program to that computer and run it on that computer.

Comment: yes (i work with multiple Macs and PCs) So my current PC is Mac298, but at a certain time I want to run the script on a pcwith the name Mac111 instead of mine, without touching that computer, just running it from mine (theyre connected and an SSH connection is possible)

Comment: Just scp the script to that computer and run it with sudo. `scp shutdown.sh user@Mac111:` then `ssh user@Mac111 "sudo ./shutdown.sh"`

Comment: so the script itself works, but when I start the script through an executable it doesnt shutdown my Mac.. It just says shutdown: NOT super-user
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

and that's it. Nothing else happens (the Mac is definitely more han 24 hours online)
If I start it on a remote Mac, it of course also won't work.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The major bug in your script is `cut` should look like:

```
uptime_days=`uptime | cut -d " " -f 4`
```

Note the `5` became a `4`.  This is because the cut was picking out the word `days`, not the number before it.

The way to catch errors like this is to add an `echo` into your code like:

```
echo uptime_days=$uptime_days
```

So when the output contains

```
uptime_days=days,
```

it is obvious some error in parsing has occurred.

There are also a couple of other things that could be improved to avoid issues later:

### shebang

The top line of the script should start with `#!` for it to be read by the kernel.  Your code is being interpreted by the shell anyway, but if you run the command in a different way it might not so making the top line look like

```
#!/bin/bash
```

is a good idea.

### double brackets

Using double brackets for conditionals in the shell is less error prone.  You can also move the `then` onto the same line with the `if` like so:

```
if [[ $uptime_days -ge $max ]]; then 
     echo shutdown!
fi
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the output of `uptime` changes depending on how long the machine is up, so for example my computer has been up for 1 minute (Yes I just rebooted). The output of uptime is `10:13  up 1 min, 12 users, load averages: 4.31 1.51 0.58` your cut command will now say that my Mac has been up for  1 day. (there is a double space between the time and the word "up").

Comment: I agree there are other issues with the script, but I felt like your answer missed the immediate issue he was having and how to avoid it in general.  You provided a solution to his overall problem without helping him understand how to script better or why parsing `uptime` is a bad idea.

Answer (score -2):

This is the whole script:

```
#!/bin/bash
uptime | grep -q days && shutdown -h now
```

Comment: tried it, now it says that the "fi" is unexpected